# TSQL - part of string with '.' char

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have string, which can be:

```
1.A.1  
1.1.A.1
```

I need SELECT which return me:

```
1. as 1stLevel, 1.A. as 2ndLevel
1. as 1stLevel, 1.1. as 2ndLevel, 1.1.A. as 3rdLevel
```

Now I solve this with substring, but have problem when come to 10, on example:

```
11.D.12.
```

Comment: Please share your current query

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: `declare @cString varchar(max) = '1.1.A.2'`

`select substring(@cString, 1, 2) as [1stLevel], substring(@cString, 1, 4) as [2ndLevel], substring(@cString, 1, 6) as [3rdLevel]`
`select left(@cString, 2) as [1stLevel], left(@cString, 4) as [2ndLevel], left(@cString, 6) as [3rdLevel]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast strings as xml and use path. You can use table valued function or substring if you are sure with length of your strings.

Xpath example:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tmp_xmldata') is not null drop table #tmp_xmldata
select cast('<a>' + replace(input.string, '.', '</a><a>') + '</a>' as xml) as XmlData
into #tmp_xmldata
from (
   select '1.A.1' as string
   union all
   select '1.1.A.1') as input

select
   *,
   XmlData.value('/a[1]', 'varchar(max)') as [1rdLevel],
   XmlData.value('/a[2]', 'varchar(max)') as [2rdLevel],
   XmlData.value('/a[3]', 'varchar(max)') as [3rdLevel],
   XmlData.value('/a[4]', 'varchar(max)') as [4rdLevel]
from #tmp_xmldata as x
```

Substring:

```
select
   string,
   substring(string, 1, 1),
   substring(string, 3, 1),
   substring(string, 5, 1),
   substring(string, 7, 1),
   substring(string, 9, 1)
from (
   select '1.A.1' as string
   union all
   select '1.1.A.1') as input
```

Or you can abuse parsename function:

```
select
   string,
   parsename(string, 1),
   parsename(string, 2),
   parsename(string, 3),
   parsename(string, 4)
from (
   select '1.A.1' as string
   union all
   select '1.1.A.1') as input
```

I cannot recomend substring, because you can have issue with non-onechar strings. Best solution is parsename function because its so simple. Limit for parsename are 4 levels.

Comment: `PARSENAME()` function  2nd argument maximum value is 4.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need with Xpath

Comment: And `ParseName` fails hard for values it doesn't expect, e.g. if the input exceeds 128 characters, has more than three dots or other reasons: `select ParseName( '1.][.3.4', 2 );`.

Answer (score 0):

We can it make it little more dynamic way by creating a user-defined function. Wwe can split the string with the help of `STRING_SPLIT` function.

**User defined function**

```
create function [dbo].[fn_level](@level varchar(100))
returns varchar(max)
as begin
    declare @retLevel as varchar(max);
    declare @t as table([rn] int identity(1, 1), [val] varchar(100));
    insert into @t([val])
    select [value] from string_split(@level, '.');
    select @retLevel = stuff((
            select ', ' + [val] + ' as Level' + cast([rn] as varchar(10))
            from @t
            for xml path('')
        )
        , 1, 2, ''
    );  
    return @retLevel;
end
```

Disclaimer: `STRING_SPLIT` function can be used in SQL Server 2016+

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/22771c/1)